# Fancybox doesn't work on mobile but works on Desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, fancybox

I am trying to get my Fancybox to work on mobile, however currently it opens but doesn't play the youtube videos.

On desktop everything works just fine, not sure why this is happening on mobile.

It currently hosted for testing on [my other website](http://www.sonirepairs.com/Videos.html) - the YouTube videos section.

HTML:

```
<div>
   <a class="youtubeFancy" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyG2i_kPZJA">
   <img src="img/youtube/chewingGum.jpg"/>
   <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a class="youtubeFancy" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ga912aEWEyQ">
   <img src="img/youtube/DeckOfCardsVanish.jpg"/>
   <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a class="youtubeFancy" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SquDtdHqfc">
   <img src="img/youtube/Warning.jpg"/>
   <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a class="youtubeFancy" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sSoYADPYlY">
   <img src="img/youtube/fizz.jpg"/>
   <img id="icon" src="img/youtubePlayIcon.png"/>
   </a>
</div>
```

Fancybox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".youtubeFancy").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
            'padding': 0,
            'autoScale': true,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/') + '&autoplay=1',
            'width': '100%',
            'type': 'iframe',
            iframe: {
                'preload': false
            },
            helpers: {
                media: {}
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Videos work on iOS 9 beta 3.

Comment: Currently using iOS 8.3

Comment: Are you not getting a plain white background popup?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong one - those work because of a different plugin - **Look at the Youtube Videos**

Comment: I see, I thought they were all YouTube...

Comment: @alan0xd7 - Oh no, the top are normal MP4 videos, the bottom are all YouTube videos (links)

Comment: Well, they seem to work too. See: [screenshot 1](http://i.imgur.com/cjrpmbP.png), [screenshot 2](http://i.imgur.com/J1yRKEU.png)